# Showing different shipping zones based on post code script using the shopify API

Tags: ruby, scripting, shopify, shopify-api

I'm trying to show the different rates depending on postcode in the shopify APP. I am currently using the script that they supply while also trying to tweak it to make it work for me. At the moment it isn't showing any post code because its meeting all the conditions.

If any one could help that would be brilliant.

```
    SHOW_RATES_FOR_ZIP_PROVINCE_COUNTRY = [
      {
        country_code: "UK",
        zip_code_match_type: :exact,
        zip_codes: ["BR"],
        rate_match_type: :exact,
        rate_names: ["Zone 1"],
      },
      
    ]
    SHOW_RATES_FOR_ZIP_PROVINCE_COUNTRY_TWO = [
      {
        country_code: "UK",
        zip_code_match_type: :exact,
        zip_codes: ["DA"],
        rate_match_type: :exact,
        rate_names: ["Zone 2"],
      },
      
    ]
    SHOW_RATES_FOR_ZIP_PROVINCE_COUNTRY_THREE = [
      {
        country_code: "UK",
        zip_code_match_type: :exact,
        zip_codes: ["TN"],
        rate_match_type: :exact,
        rate_names: ["Zone 3"],
      },
      
    ]
    
    # ================================ Script Code (do not edit) ================================
    # ================================================================
    # ZipCodeSelector
    #
    # Finds whether the supplied zip code matches any of the entered
    # strings.
    # ================================================================
    class ZipCodeSelector
      def initialize(match_type, zip_codes)
        @comparator = match_type == :exact ? '==' : 'include?'
        @zip_codes = zip_codes.map { |zip_code| zip_code.upcase.strip }
      end
    
      def match?(zip_code)
        @zip_codes.any? { |zip| zip_code.to_s.upcase.strip.send(@comparator, zip) }
      end
    end
    
    # ================================================================
    # RateNameSelector
    #
    # Finds whether the supplied rate name matches any of the entered
    # names.
    # ================================================================
    class RateNameSelector
      def initialize(match_type, rate_names)
        @match_type = match_type
        @comparator = match_type == :exact ? '==' : 'include?'
        @rate_names = rate_names&.map { |rate_name| rate_name.downcase.strip }
      end
    
      def match?(shipping_rate)
        if @match_type == :all
          true
        else
          @rate_names.any? { |name| shipping_rate.name.downcase.send(@comparator, name) }
        end
      end
    end
    
    # ================================================================
    # ShowRatesForZipProvinceCountryCampaign
    #
    # If the cart's shipping address zip/province/country match the
    # entered settings, the entered rate(s) are shown, and all other
    # rates are hidden. Otherwise, the entered rate(s) are hidden.
    # ================================================================
    class ShowRatesForZipProvinceCountryCampaign
      def initialize(campaigns)
        @campaigns = campaigns
      end
    
      def run(cart, shipping_rates)
        address = cart.shipping_address
    
        @campaigns.each do |campaign|
          zip_code_selector = ZipCodeSelector.new(campaign[:zip_code_match_type], campaign[:zip_codes])
          rate_name_selector = RateNameSelector.new(campaign[:rate_match_type], campaign[:rate_names])
    
          if address.nil?
            full_match = false
          else
            country_match =  address.country_code.upcase.strip == campaign[:country_code].upcase.strip
            # province_match = address.province_code.upcase.strip == campaign[:province_code].upcase.strip
            zip_match = zip_code_selector.match?(address.zip)
            full_match = country_match && province_match && zip_match
          end
          
          shipping_rates.delete_if do |shipping_rate|
            rate_name_selector.match?(shipping_rate) != full_match
          end
        end
      end
    end
    
    CAMPAIGNS = [
      ShowRatesForZipProvinceCountryCampaign.new(SHOW_RATES_FOR_ZIP_PROVINCE_COUNTRY),
      ShowRatesForZipProvinceCountryCampaign.new(SHOW_RATES_FOR_ZIP_PROVINCE_COUNTRY_THREE),
      ShowRatesForZipProvinceCountryCampaign.new(SHOW_RATES_FOR_ZIP_PROVINCE_COUNTRY_TWO),
    ]
    
    CAMPAIGNS.each do |campaign|
        campaign.run(Input.cart, Input.shipping_rates)
    end
    
    
    Output.shipping_rates = Input.shipping_rates
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific. What is your expected result for a sample code A. What is your expected result for a sample code B. And on... and on. Those scripts work awesome, but without knowing what you are looking for, I doubt anyone will provide you any answers of much value.